# How do I correcly show a loading spinner while a download is being prepared with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, download, loading

Let's say I want my users to download a text file via a button. This works fine, I just want to show a loading animation I prepared while the text file is loaded on the backend. Tests show a few lines don't take much time, but larger transactions may do. I've implemented the following Ajax lines:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: "success",
    error: "error",
    beforeSend: function () { $('#loaderAnim').show(); },
    complete: function () { $('#loaderAnim').hide(); },      
    type: 'GET', dataType: 'json'
});
```

Question is, does this approach grant me proper request timing or am I just pinging my url?

Comment: If you prefer javascript then thiis could be worth to see: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader5.  They have shown the loader on page load. Just add the function defined in it on your button's onclick event. There you go! Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also refer to this: http://jsfiddle.net/gK9wH/9/ This one is elegant.

Comment: From the code, it seems that you not using response data, so i think you should hide loader in success function. (When server response is 200 OK, not any error)